# The present continuous tense vs. the future continuous tense

Tags: grammar

> I am working tomorrow.
>
> I will be working tomorrow.

I know these two sentences mean the same thing for planned future action, but which one is better to use?

Comment: It's 'continuous', by the way, and 'action'. Acton is in London.

Answer (score 1):

`I am working tomorrow` feels informal compared to`I will be working tomorrow`.

Which is better depends entirely on how appropriate it is to be formal in whatever situation you find yourself in.

Answer (score 1):

They are usually the same meaning.

A small difference sometimes exists. "I am working tomorrow" sounds a little less defensive, as if it is an unalterable thing, with a hint of "I have no control over the matter".  "I will be working tomorrow" has a hint of "I have chosen to work tomorrow and will not alter my plans to do so".

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're being unusually vehement ("I *will* be working tomorrow, even if it kills me!"), the grammatically proper way of expressing your intention is "I shall be working tomorrow."

I suspect many people confuse *shall* and *will*, because both words produce the same contraction. For example, when someone says "I'll be working tomorrow." they might mean "I shall be working tomorrow, as usual." or they might mean "I will be working tomorrow and damn the strike!"

That said, very few people seem to use *shall* these days, and I'm fairly sure that almost everyone who says "I'll be working tomorrow." would say that it's short for "I will be.." without any sense of vehemence.

Comment: Rather than risk the wrath of [descriptivists](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/descriptivismterm.htm) on board the EL&U, perhaps it would be more correct to assert the following: *"I shall be ...." used to be considered the grammatically proper..."* :)

Comment: "I am going to be working", "I am going to work tomorrow" or "I will work tomorrow" haven't been suggested yet, so for the sake of completeness, here they are.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Mari-Lou. I was sure this site would contain a lively prescriptivist/descriptivist division of opinion. (I tend to fall somewhere in the middle, but with prescriptivist leanings.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the action is being done with intention or not so in working probably you work in an organization so the time table or the program obliges u to work at a particular days so if we say I am working tomorrow you mean that you have an intention now and the intention will be done by tomorrow

Comment: Do you not think it would be appropriate, on an English Language website, to use proper sentences and punctuation ? And do you really think it is appropriate to write 'you' as 'u' ?